# IdentityServer3 Login page add Application Name via IdentityServerOptions?

Tags: identityserver3

In identityServer3 using the default embedded login page I have set the SiteName to a custom value just fine.

I would like to have the default login page display the name of the client application that routed them to the login page...  Is that possible or will I need to role my own page?

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "My Authenitcation Services", 
            SigningCertificate = SigningCertificate,
            Factory = factory
        };
```

Comment: Look at the LoginPageViewModel -- that has the data available to your JS code on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

To show a custom application name and such you need to override the partial view.  IdentityServer3 Sample: EmbeddedAssetsViewService  shows how to do this exactly.
Basicly...

1. In your identityServer Application add a templates folder in the site.
2. Copy their _login.html file and put inside this folder.
3. In your IdentityServerOptions set the SiteName = "What Ever you want",
4. The build and run your client application that pulls up the login page.

You should be good to go... 
Finding the sample code example can be a bit difficult... 
Where to download the sample code: [ [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples) ]
**Here is the sample code location in the samples download:**

```
..\IdentityServer3.Samples-master\source\DefaultViewService\EmbeddedAssetsViewService
```